# How to disable the correct button in a for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a 1-8 rows (with their own button) and I want to correctly disable each button when the user. Right now, it is just disabling the last button when any button is clicked. Any idea what I am doing wrong? How can I correctly disable the button when it is a for loop?

```
class ResolveSourceContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        modalOpen: false,
        updated: [],
        key: 0,
    };
}

disableRow = (key) => {
    let {updated} = this.state
    updated.push(key)
    this.setState({updated})
}

render() {

    const { size, modalOpen} = this.state;
    let {key} = this.state
    const { element} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal size={size} open={modalOpen} onClose={this.closeModal}>
                <Modal.Content style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <div className='ird-modal'>
                        <Modal.Header>
                            {`${element.lid}`}
                        </Modal.Header>
                    </div>
                    <Table>
            <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Type</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Update</Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                        {Object.keys(element.auditdiff).map(function(dataType){
                            if (dataType !== "Lid" && dataType !== "Datacenter" && dataType !=="Id") 
                            return (
                                Object.keys(element.auditdiff[dataType]).map(function(data){
                                    {key++}
                                    return (
                                        <Table.Row key = {i}>
                                            <Table.Cell>{data + " " + dataType}</Table.Cell>
                                            <Table.Cell>
                                            <Button content='Update Row' color='green' disabled = {updated.indexOf(key) >-1} //not correctly disabling the button
                                                onClick = {() =>  {this.disableRow(key)} } 
                                                />
                                            </Table.Cell>
                                        </Table.Row>
                                        );
                                    })
                            )})
                        }

                        </Table.Header>
                </Table>
                </Modal.Content>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use concat to setState, instead of push. concat will return a new array, but push is just adding new item to your original array

Second, you are directly modifying key state by {key++}. You actually don't need key state, you can use the index in map function.

```js
class ResolveSourceContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        modalOpen: false,
        updated: [],
        key: 0,
    };
}

disableRow = (key) => {
    let {updated} = this.state
    this.setState({updated: updated.concat([key])})
}

render() {

    const { size, modalOpen} = this.state;
    let {key} = this.state
    const { element} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal size={size} open={modalOpen} onClose={this.closeModal}>
                <Modal.Content style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <div className='ird-modal'>
                        <Modal.Header>
                            {`${element.lid}`}
                        </Modal.Header>
                    </div>
                    <Table>
            <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Type</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Update</Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                        {Object.keys(element.auditdiff).map(function(dataType){
                            if (dataType !== "Lid" && dataType !== "Datacenter" && dataType !=="Id") 
                            return (
                                Object.keys(element.auditdiff[dataType]).map(function(data, index){
                                    return (
                                        <Table.Row key = {index}>
                                            <Table.Cell>{data + " " + dataType}</Table.Cell>
                                            <Table.Cell>
                                            <Button content='Update Row' color='green' disabled = {updated.indexOf(index) >-1} //not correctly disabling the button
                                                onClick = {() =>  {this.disableRow(index)} } 
                                                />
                                            </Table.Cell>
                                        </Table.Row>
                                        );
                                    })
                            )})
                        }

                        </Table.Header>
                </Table>
                </Modal.Content>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Problem #1: You are mutating state object!

**Issue:** Pushing new value *into existing* array and storing back in state

```
disableRow = (key) => {
  let {updated} = this.state
  updated.push(key) // <--- mutating current array reference
  this.setState({updated})
}
```

**Solution:** Copy previous array *and* new value *into* a new array

```
disableRow = (key) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    updated: [...prevState.updated, key],
  }));
}
```

## Problem #2: You aren't using consistent keys to identify rows, they update each render cycle.

**Solution:** Use keys for each data element unique within the dataset, like id's, names, etc.. keys for the same elements should persist through re-renders.